# Implementing custom atributes for claims based security

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, claims-based-identity

I am trying to implement claims based security using System.IdentityModel. We are using Windows XP for all development work and therefore cannot use Windows Identity Foundation. What I am trying to do is decorate methods in service contract with permission attributes, I am not sure how to do that

For example in my service I want to have method

void DeleteRecord(int recordId);

I want to decorate it with an attribute like this

[HasDeletePermission]
void DeleteRecord(int recordId);

So based on the claimset user has, method will either execute or exception will be thrown. How do I achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used PostSharp free edition to implement attribute. Works well

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/) to embed aspects into the methods you need.